# This code worked fine until we started getting error like Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With' statement

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am an absolute beginner. Trying to change some css and upload the asp.net website. Found few errors.
Following code shows error. It supposed o display video on the front page.

> Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With'
>   statement.    line    216  column  29  Leading '.' or '!' can only appear
>   inside a 'With' statement.                 218                      49
>   Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With' statement.
>   223                     99

```vb
If IsDBNull(.Rows(0).Item("Image")) Then
Else
    Dim strFileName As String = .Rows(0).Item("Image")
    Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~\Video Images\" & strFileName)
    Dim file As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(path)

    If file.Exists Then
       VideoImage.InnerHtml = "<img class='ThumbnailImage' src='Video Images/" & .Rows(0).Item("Image") & "' alt='' border='0' align='left'"
                            VideoImage.InnerHtml &= "style='width: 59px; height: 74px' />"
    End If
End If
End If
```

Highly appreciate any help.I tried to insert with and endwith but don’t know where to be inserted. So failed.

Answer (score 0):

5th line from the bottom: instead of `.Rows(0).Item("Image")` try `Rows(0).Item("Image")` ...that should be the error.

Also: instead of

```vb
If IsDBNull(Rows(0).Item("Image")) Then Else
```

Which means "If `IsDBNull(...)` is true, then do nothing, if it's false do (your code)" try

```vb
If Not IsDBNull(Rows(0).Item("Image")) Then
```

Which means, "If `IsDBNull(...)` is not true, then do (your code)"

In all places, you have `.Rows(0).Item("Image"))` where you should have `Rows(0).Item("Image))`. The dot (.) is an operator, it should be used with something to the left of it. It's used to access something within another thing, for example `Rows(0).Item("Image"))` accesses the `Item()` function within the `Rows` object. Saying `.Rows.Item(("Image"))` is like trying to access the `Rows` property of nothing, because there's nothing before the first `.` :)

Altogether your code should look like:

```vb
If Not IsDBNull(Rows(0).Item("Image")) Then 
    Dim strFileName As String = Rows(0).Item("Image") 
    Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~\\Video Images\\" & strFileName) 
    Dim file As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(path)
    If file.Exists Then
        VideoImage.InnerHtml = "<img class='ThumbnailImage' src='Video Images/" & .Rows(0).Item("Image") & "' alt='' border='0' align='left'"
        VideoImage.InnerHtml &= "style='width: 59px; height: 74px'"
    End If
End If
```

Also, I used double-backslashes because `\"` in `Server.MapPath("~\Video Images\" & strFileName)` will escape away the second double-quote, messing up the syntax highlighting here on StackOverflow and *maybe* messing up your code too. I'm not sure what your setup is; you may want to use what was in your original code.

Comment: I hope that helps. The reason for your error is almost definitely the places where you have `.Rows` but I can't guarantee that your code will work after you fix that.

Comment: I tried first part, thett is removing '.' and got this error.Error 28 'Rows' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Is there a `table` variable somewhere? If you have some code somewhere that gets your SQL table then you'll want to use `table.Rows(0)`

Comment: This is where the `With` statement comes in, you could say: `With table` as the new top line, then use `.Rows(0).Item("Image")` which would refer to `table.Rows(0).Item("Image)` and put an `End With` as the new bottom line

Comment: I am sorry but it still throws same error. I'd like to paste complete code, but I'm afraid here it's exceeding the permitted characters. so I am posting it as a new question. Hope to see you there.